# Как сделать глобальную переменную для всех моделей в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет!

Встал довольно интересный вопрос. Есть приложенька на ларе, вся разбита на систему аккаунтов для каждой компании (по типу CRM). Не путайте аккаунт компании с юзером, это разное.

У аккаунта компании есть slug, по которому приложенька определяет, к какой компании обращается человек. Т.е., к примеру, следующий роут:
`/account/*company_slug*/deals` вернет сделки компании, у которой slug = *company_slug*.

На группу роутов с префиксом `/account/*company_slug*/` установлен мидлвар, который проверяет, есть ли у текущего юзера роль на выполнение действий в аккаунте компании *company_slug*.

При этом каждая модель, которая относится к определенной компании, имеет в таблице поле account_id, которое определяет аккаунт, к которой она относится и не дает другим компаниям получить доступ к чужой инфе.

Но вот задача: во всех таблицах связь идет именно по id в account, а мы на входе получаем из url только slug аккаунта. Вопрос: каким образом нам для всего дальнейшего функционирования приложения получить id аккаунта по slug'у, который будет доступен из любой модели, сервиса и контроллера? 
Что можно сделать, чтобы избежать использования глобальных переменных?

Comment: Можно как вариант записать нужную вам переменную в сессию (не самый лучший вариант, но сработает)

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=DB::table('account')->where('company_slug',$slug)->value('id');
```